# Prevent hover event from binding to the childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

HTML:

```
<a id="test" data-value="1">TEST <i class="fa fa-bank"></i></a>
```

JS:

```
var f = function(e) {
    console.log($(e.target).data('value'));   
};

$('a#test').hover(f, f);
```

When I hover out from the right side of the anchor. The target of the hover out event will be `<i class="fa fa-bank"></i>`. Is there a way that I can force the target be the `<a id="test">...</a>`

Comment: Why not using `this`? Why would you have to use the target property of the event? BTW, if same handler is called for in/out and as ID must be unique on document context, just use: `$('#test').hover(f);`

Comment: @A.Wolff I would post that as the answer.

Comment: Because I have some data in the anchor.

Comment: @waitingkuo That will not prevent you using `this` in the handler...?

Comment: @waitingkuo So what's wrong with using `$(this).data('value')` ??? If you have specific issue, then at least provide specific example which replicate your issue

Comment: I misunderstood the usage of `e.target`

Comment: Please post it as the answer. I'll accept it. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside event handler will refer to the element which event is bound, so you can use instead:

```
$(this).data('value')
```

Comment: Thank you. I misused `e.target` instead